# C++: Std::cout buffer error? Jumbled output using std::cout on string variable and string literal

Tags: c++, string, c++11, vector, cout

In advance, sorry for the length of this. I have a project I am developing in tandem with three other people for an Intro Comp. Sci. course and I have arrived at a point where I honestly need to ask for some help after several hours of searching and tweaking my output/functions/classes.

Our program is a warehouse shopper's club client/inventory manager comprised of a client-interface control class, *'Members'*, to be used in main, which includes several vectors of data classes (club member classes: *'Regular'*(base) and *'Executive'*(derived), and item classes: *'Item_Info'*(derived) for purchase info and *'Item'*(base) for inventory info.) Here is the definition:

```
class Members{
  friend class RegularMember ;
  friend class ExecutiveMember ;
  friend class Item ;  // unnecessary? should use access functions
                     // all three may be unneeded
  private:
    vector <RegularMember*> memberList ;  // one member list
    vector<Item_Info> item_sales ;
    vector<Item> inventory ;
    ifstream inFile ;
    vector<string> strFiles ;
```

We use base class pointers as the *'memberList'* vector type to allow polymorphism, but are choosing to keep *'inventory' and 'item_sales'* separate for the sake of readability/functionality (*Item*(base) & *Item_Info*(derived) have unique *[stock/sold]Quantity* member variables that are used differently and this made the most sense).

Getting into the actual errors, we have two forms of input when our program runs: list of members file, containing all information relevant to the *'memberList'*, and the dayX of sales files, of which there are 5 and contain all the information relevant to *'inventory' & 'item_sales'* along with a *memberID* for each purchase, connecting each purchase to a member. We have a function to read the member input file and build out the *'memberList'*, and a function to read the day of sales files, and build out *inventory* if it is empty. I've been able to clear up all memory leaks, conditional jumps, uninitialized values, and other easily fixed problems with valgrind.

However, now that my input function is successfully proceeding through its logic and outputting for each inventory addition, I've got a very strange problem. When I try to simply output a string variable concatenated with a string literal:

```
std::cout << itemTitle << " inventory\'d\n" ;
```

I get in my console output:

```
" inventory'd"+[whatever part of the string exceeds 13 characters (the length of my string literal.)]
```

Essentially, if *itemTitle* is "Banana", you won't see any output beyond " inventory'd!", but if it is an *itemTitle* like "Panasonic Widescreen" you'll see " inventory'd!escreen". I've exhausted what feels like every possible formatting permutations using endl, as my first guess is this is some kind of stream buffer problem, but I am still unsure of what's even going on. I've also tried moving the output to execute after *itemTitle* is passed to its respective object and pushed into its vector using getter member functions, but to no avail. Outputting the return of my *getName* function results in the same as outputting the *itemTitle* variable.

If anyone would like more context on the input function, it is lengthy at ~85 lines, but if it's useful:

```
void Members::inputDayOfSales(int day_i) {  // input day of sales file
  int j, i = 0 ;
  int m, d, y, quantity, tmpint ;
  double memberID, price ;
  string itemTitle, day = to_string(day_i), file = "day.txt" ;
  file.insert(size_t(3),day) ;
  inFile.open(file) ;
  for(int i = 0 ; i < memberList.size() ; ++i)  //valgrind errors?
    memberList[i]->setSpentToday(0,day_i) ;
  while (inFile >> m) {
    i = 0 ;
    inFile.get() ;
    inFile >> d ;
    inFile.get() ;
    inFile >> y ;
    inFile >> memberID ;
    cout << endl << memberID << endl ;
    inFile.ignore(100, '\n') ;
    getline(inFile, itemTitle) ;
    inFile >> price ;
    inFile >> quantity ;
    cout << "Grabbed file info block\n" ; // grabs all the data from file
    while(1) 
      {
        if(i < memberList.size())
          {
            if(memberList[i]->getInfo().memberID == memberID) 
              {
                break ;  // once found, break from loop    
              }
            ++i ;
          }
      } 
    cout << memberList[i]->getInfo().memberID << endl << endl ;    
    tmpint = memberList[i]->getSpentToday(day_i) ;
    memberList[i]->setSpentToday((price * quantity), day_i) ;
    memberList[i]->addtoTotalSpent(price * quantity) ;
    j = 0 ;
    if(!inventory.empty()) {
      while(j < inventory.size()) {
        if(inventory[j].getName() == itemTitle
                             || j == inventory.size()-1) {
          break ;
        }
        ++j ;
      }
      if(inventory[j].getName() == itemTitle) {
        cout << endl ;
        cout << "Already inventory'd!\n" ;
        Item_Info newsale ; 
        Date saleDate(m,d,y) ;

        newsale.setPurchaseDate(saleDate) ;
        newsale.setRevenue(price*quantity) ;
        newsale.setSoldQuantity(quantity) ;

        item_sales.push_back(newsale) ;
      }
      else {
        newinv_l:
        Item newinv ;
        Item_Info newsale ;
        Date saleDate(m,d,y) ;
        newinv.setName(itemTitle) ;
        newinv.setPrice(price) ;
        newsale.setPurchaseDate(saleDate) ;
        newsale.setRevenue(price*quantity) ;
        newsale.setSoldQuantity(quantity) ;
        item_sales.push_back(newsale) ;
        inventory.push_back(newinv) ;
        cout << "\n" ;
        // all three are having the same issue:
        //cout << itemTitle ;
        //cout << newinv.getName() ;
        //cout << inventory.back().getName() ;
        cout << " inventory\'d!" << endl ;
      }
    }
    else if(inventory.empty()) goto newinv_l ;

    i = 0 ;
  }
  inFile.ignore(100, '\n') ;
  inFile.close() ;
}
```

Comment: Is there a return (`'\r'`) character at the end of `itemTitle`?

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm, there may be. The function is reading values in from a file that separates each variable with a return so would this be the case that the extraction operator is picking up the '\r' and I need to devise a way to separate it from my string?

Comment: Yes, because when that `\r` is printed out, the next character will be at the beginning of the line (overwriting the character that is already there).

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm It was indeed a return character at the end of my string that was causing all of my confusion! I specified '\r' as the third parameter on the getline call for itemTitle and my output fixed right up. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Moving the speculation from comments into an answer:

You have a return (`'\r'`) character at the end of your `itemTitle` string.  When this is printed, the point that the next character will be output is moved back to the left side of the console.  When output, the next character will overwrite the first one that was printed.